# What is the optimum width for a website (desktop version)?

Tags: web-deployment

I have a wordpress blog and I use a responsive theme. I want to increase my site width. Currently its width is 1050px ( main-container). I wish to expand it to the 1200px or 1280px.

Before change it, I want to know what is the optimum width for a web site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding this correctly, but

100% as that's the only width that will display at full width in all browsers. Do this in your CSS, like:

```
body{
    font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin:0;
        background:#383838;
    width:100%;
    color:#444444;
```

Comment: Actually I'm not ask this type of thing. I need to know optimum width (maximum) for a website?

Comment: Using 100% width is a *very bad idea*. The website will likely be very difficult to use on high resolution screens such as 1440p and 1080p.